# how to run virginbroadband from usb in 11.10?

Tags: usb, modem, broadband

i need to know how to install and run this virgin broadband from ubuntu 11.10. from australia. I have the username, password and APN but it does not seem to connect. ANy help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: is it a mobile broadband connection using a usb modem

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the USB Modem to see if there is any memory card already inserted
2. Remove any onboard memory card
3. Connect the modem and wait for network manager to detect the modem (time can range from a second to 5 minutes top)
4. Once network manager detects the device as a modem as a mobile broadband device, click on the NETWORK indicator and choose the your device as detected and you should see network ICON rotating( indicating that the system is trying to make a connection)
5. A CONNECTION ESTABLISHED notification will spring up if the connection is successful
6. IF network manager fails to recognize the device as a mobile broadband device, remove the device and click on the network indicator, select EDIT CONNECTIONS
7. A NETWORK CONNECTIONS dialog box will show up. Click on MOBILE BROADBAND and choose ADD.
8. Choose continue and also choose the country from which you are making the connection( Australia  in your case) and select the provider from the list of providers (virgin broadband in your case) and click continue.
9. if you do't find your provider name make it manually.
10. Finally choose apply and connect the USB Modem and wait for about 5 minutes to allow network manager to recognize the device as a mobile broadband device. Once recognized, click on the device name under the network indicator to activate the connection

Comment: tried that, it says. it detects the usb as a modem and the connection comes up but it doesnt connect.

Comment: what it shows up and please provide some more details about your modem its manufacturer and its model no.

Comment: The usb is detected in the shortcuts on my cairodock. But it says 'unmounted'. When i try to manually set up a connection, the modem is detected but doesnt seem to connect to the internet. IT says "HUAWEI mobile connect" Model E169 HSDPA USB stick + FCC ID: QISE 169. HOpe this is useful. HAribol